# RegEx for phone number, all zeros not allowed

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Need your help for RegEx. My current RegEx is **/^\d{8,}$/** - minimum length is 8, no letters, special characters and spaces allowed. I would also like to disallow all zeros like 00000000

Thanks!

Comment: What if my phone number is 500-0000?

Comment: Use c# code for that. Not much difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This pattern should meet your needs: `^(?!0+$)\d{8,}$`

The `(?!0+$)` portion is a negative lookahead that will prevent an input of just zeros.

Example:

```
var pattern = @"^(?!0+$)\d{8,}$";
var inputs = new[]
{
    "00000000",         // false
    "(123) 456-789",    // false
    "123",              // false
    "01234567",         // true
    "500000000",        // true
    "123456789"         // true
};

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern), input);
}
```