# Regex for US cell phone number with all zeros not being allowed

Tags: c#, regex

I have a cellphone field that is being validated as such-

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Cell phone is required"),
            RegularExpression(Constants.PhoneRegex, ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone number")]
public string CellPhone { get; set; }
```

This is currently being validated for US phone numbers with this regex,
`PhoneRegex = @"^(?!0+$)(\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4}))$";`
which I found from https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s02.html

Now there is a new requirement to not allow user to enter all zeros. So I tried `^(?!0+$)(\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4}))$` which I found from another thread [RegEx for phone number, all zeros not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985306/regex-for-phone-number-all-zeros-not-allowed)

This one works when I test it on https://rubular.com/ but in my code it does not work

```
Example:-
Cellphone   |  Actual   |  Expected
------------------------------------
4561237890  |  //true   |  true
1234        |  //false  |  false
0000000000  |  //true   |  false
```

Comment: As an aside, is there much point to this? A user who is entering all zeros is obviously not interested in giving you their number, as that's very unlikely to be an input error. Disallowing all zeros will just encourage them to come up with a more creative way of not entering their number (like making the last digit `1`). If a valid number is a hard requirement, send a verification message to the number; if not, excessive parsing isn't likely to get you better data.

Comment: The pattern itself seems to work, see  https://ideone.com/COA3bS

Comment: @Thefourthbird The part where the code checks the input against the regex fails; `RegularExpression(Constants.PhoneRegex, ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone number")`. I'm validating it through the UI.

Comment: As a side note, no US area code can start with 0 or 1 so any 10 digit US phone number starting with 0 or 1 is invalid

Comment: Try `^(?!(?:\D*0)+\D*$)\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Please please [read this](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md). And consider [using this](https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp) .

Comment: Also, there's no law that says every validation problem must be solved with a single massive regular expression that is too complex for any single person to understand. This is an example where you could combine two simpler regular expressions in a custom validator. One to match the general shape, and another to reject all-zero.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, This regex worked

Comment: You have recently obtained voting privileges, kindly [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answers (see [how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/)) that you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!(?:\D*0)+\D*$)\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:\D*0)+\D*$)` - no only one or more `0` digits in the string
- `\(?` - an optional `(` char
- `[0-9]{3}` - three digits
- `\)?` - an optional `)` char
- `[-. ]?` - an optional space, `-` or `.` char
- `[0-9]{3}` - three digits
- `[-. ]?` - an optional space, `-` or `.` char
- `[0-9]{4}` - four digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var regEx = @"^(?<Number>[0-9]{3}[-.\s][0-9]{3}[-.\s][0-9]{4})(?<AllZero>[0]{0,9})$";
var match = Regex.Match(MYSTRING_TO_TEST, regEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string validateNumber = match.Groups["Number"].Value;
string allZeroNumber = match.Groups["AllZero"].Value;
```

If allZeroNumber match is all 0 digit.